# Recurrence of Brownian motion in one-dimension

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

I am studying Brownian Motion from Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*.

In Theorem 7.2.9, Durrett claimed that one-dimensional Brownian motion is recurrent. The complete statement of the theorem is:

> Let $B_t$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and let $A = \cap_n\{B_t = 0$ for some $t \geq n\}$. Then $P_x(A) = 1$ for all $x$.

The reason is because with probability $1$, $\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_t/\sqrt{t} = \infty$ and $\lim \inf_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_t/\sqrt{t} = -\infty$ for any one dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$ starting at $0$, the translation invariance property, and the continuity of Brownian paths.

I can understand the translation invariance property part; its role is to offset the $x$ in $P_x(A)$ (please correct me if I'm wrong), but the remaining part does not seem very obvious to me.

**Question:** Why does $\lim \sup_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_t/\sqrt{t} = \infty$, $\lim \inf_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_t/\sqrt{t} = -\infty$, and continuity implies $P_x(A) = 1$ for all $x$?

Comment: By the intermediate value Theorem.

Comment: The handwaving intuitive argument is that if at any time $s$ you have $B_s>0$ then, since $\liminf\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} B_t/\sqrt{t} = -\infty$, there will be some $t>s$ with $B_t <0$, and by continuity some intermediate $r$ with $B_r =0$.  Similarly with $B_s <0$ or $B_s =0$.  So at any point in time there will be a future point in time when $B_r=0$.  This is not a totally rigorous argument, but it is true with probability $1$